# Is there a simple javascript API for Google Drive?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

The Google Drive API looks more complicated to me than I would like, with all the stuff about authorization, client-ids, scopes, boundaries, delimiters and so on.

If I have javascript code in a browser, and I am logged into my Google account, I was more hoping for a simpler API something like:

```
google.drive.saveFile(path, contents, statusCallback);
google.drive.loadFile(path, onLoadCallback);
```

I guess there could be some extra parameters depending on the type of data being stored (e.g. string, binary), but something along these lines.

Is there a Javascript wrapper for Google Drive that provides something simple like this?

Comment: Have you checked github? https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=google+drive&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: those all require auth. only easy way is on the answer about apps script.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Apps Script and the [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app).

Comment: apps script is the way. if you need something client-side, its possible with a chrome extension (by reusing the cookie/auth of the drive page)

Comment: Looks promising, though I was hoping for more of a pure client-side Javascript wrapper of the Driva API.